# When will Edubuntu 18.04 LTS be released?

Tags: edubuntu

May I know when Edubuntu 18.04 LTS will be released?
Edubuntu is Ubuntu for education. It skipped 16.04 LTS so the next upgrade is 18.04 LTS.

Comment: Does Edubuntu even qualify as an official flavour anymore? IIRC you lose that status if you skip too many releases.

Answer (score 5):

Going by [this March 2016 mailing list post](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/edubuntu-devel/2016-March/003884.html) from Stéphane Graber who was leading the project then with Jonathan Carter, never:

> That's why I'm announcing today that Edubuntu will NOT be releasing a
> 16.04 LTS version. Instead, Jonathan and I will focus on ongoing support of Edubuntu 14.04 LTS until it goes EOL in April 2019.
>
> That's not to say that Edubuntu is dead, at least not yet.
>
> While Jonathan and I will solely focus on fulfilling our promise of
> support for Edubuntu 14.04 LTS, new contributors are absolutely
> welcome to take over the Edubuntu project and shape it to their
> liking.
>
> The two of us will be happy to sponsor any Edubuntu related uploads,
> will help new contributors get Edubuntu membership and then hold
> elections to setup a new Edubuntu Council which would finally take the
> whole project over from us.
>
> Should none of that happen by the time Ubuntu 17.10 is released,
> Jonathan and I will ask the Technical Board to revoke Edubuntu as an
> official flavour and will be removing any leftover packages from the
> archive, remove our seeds and any cdimage build integration,
> effectively removing Edubuntu from the Ubuntu release process.

There had been no further activity on the mailing list for a few years after April 2016, not counting spam. <strike>Nothing has happened since then, there have been further point releases for Ubuntu proper, but not Edubuntu. All told, the project appears dead.</strike>

---

However, a new team led by Erich and Amy Eickmeyer have pulled through to release [Edubuntu 23.04](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/edubuntu-23-04-released/35281)! From [the mailing list post announcing the beta](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/edubuntu-devel/2023-April/003893.html):

> This isn’t the Edubuntu you once knew! Gone are the days of the Linux
> Terminal Server Project (LTSP), which was long-since spun off into its own.
> Instead, we’re focusing on making classroom and parental administration
> easy.

Comment: That's great news! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

All the *.04 releases are released at the end of april, so **if** there will be an Edubuntu 18.04 release it is surely going to be released at the end of april of 2018.

However, if you're looking just for Edubuntu's educational software and artwork, they are available **in every Ubuntu** via the following packages:

- `ubuntu-edu-preschool` - Preschool educational application bundle
- `ubuntu-edu-primary` - Primary (ages 6–12) educational application bundle
- `ubuntu-edu-secondary` - Secondary (ages 13–18) educational application bundle
- `ubuntu-edu-tertiary` - Tertiary (university level) educational application bundle
- `edubuntu-desktop` - all Edubuntu packages including artwork

(see the [edubuntu.org download page](http://edubuntu.org/download))

To install, just do: `sudo apt install`*packagename*